# Check if a class has a field by string

Tags: php

I would Google this, but honestly I have no idea what to search for

Say I have this class

```
class a
{
    public $a_a, $a_b, $a_c;
}

$true = "a_a";
$false = "a_e";
```

How do I use the strings to prove that the class contains the field a_a, but not a_e ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

- [`property_exists`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) —  Checks if the object or class has a property

In your case:

```
var_dump( property_exists('a', 'a_a') ); // TRUE
```

You could also use the [Reflection API](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasproperty.php), but that's overkill for this UseCase:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('a');
var_dump( $reflector->hasProperty('a_e') ); // FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`property_exists`](http://php.net/property_exists) or [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php). But you should know that before PHP 5.3 `property_exists` checked the visibility of the property, too. So, if you are using PHP 5.2 and want to check the existence of a private property you must use Reflection.